# How to create an instance of android.opengl.EGLContext object?

Tags: android, webrtc

I have this function (taken from webRTC api) :

```
  public static EglBase createEgl14(
      android.opengl.EGLContext sharedContext) {...}
```

So i need to call it with an instance of `android.opengl.EGLContext`. I have the handle (long) of the context, but I can't find a way to create an `android.opengl.EGLContext` object

when i do:

```
new EGLContext(myContextHandle)
```

i receive

> error: EGLContext(long) is not public in EGLContext; cannot be
>   accessed from outside package

this is the implementation of EGLContext :

```
public class EGLContext extends EGLObjectHandle {
    private EGLContext(long handle) {
        super(handle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof EGLContext)) return false;

        EGLContext that = (EGLContext) o;
        return getNativeHandle() == that.getNativeHandle();
    }
}
```

Comment: EglBase.createEgl14(...).getEglBaseContext()

Answer (score 0):

Simply call [EGL14.eglCreateContext()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/EGL14#eglCreateContext(android.opengl.EGLDisplay,%20android.opengl.EGLConfig,%20android.opengl.EGLContext,%20int%5B%5D,%20int)) to create a `EGLContext`. The signature of this method is

```
public static EGLContext eglCreateContext (EGLDisplay dpy, 
                EGLConfig config, 
                EGLContext share_context, 
                int[] attrib_list, 
                int offset)
```

If you are not familiar with OpenGL. You should check out the Grafika project for [reference](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/b1df331e89cffeab621f02b102d4c2c25eb6088a/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/gles/EglCore.java#L102) to see how to create one.